# Looping using SharePoint Designer 2013 to show available users

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, workflow, designer-workflow

I have a task. I have a list called tickets where a user can submit trouble tickets. In addition, I have 3 engineers who handles these. If Engineer 1 receives the ticket he can either approve the ticket for completion or reject it due to not being able to solve it. Once rejected, it moves on to Engineer 2 and so forth. I have to be able to ***visually show*** that when Engineer 2 is solving a ticket that Engineer 1 failed to do, then Engineer 1 will be ***shown as available*** to receive the next trouble ticket due to the unresolved ticket being escalated to Engineer 2. Is this all possible in SharePoint Designer without the use of VS? If so, please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Yes with the help of SharePoint Designer 2013 it is possible as it contains the stages to move on. If one engineer 1 is not able to work on ticket and rejected the same it will move to next stage 2 engineer also set the counter to 0 of Engineer 1.